# Filter an array of objects, checking only specified properties and child objects

Tags: javascript

The function filterList recieves an array of objects and filters the list, checking only the properties of the object specified in a 'filterFields' array.

It compares the values of those specified properties to a string 'filterTerm' using a comparison function.

If the property specified by 'filterFields' is an array or object, it also checks through those and returns the entire top-level object if the specified fields of any child objects are matched with the comparison function.

I would like to check to see if this is normal/sensible javascript and whether there is a better way of writing this functionality, performance-wise.

````
    //if filterTerm or filterFields are empty, return original list
    function filterList(list, filterTerm, filterFields) {
        if(filterTerm && filterFields.length > 0) {
            return list.filter(filterCallback(filterFields, filterTerm));
        }else{
            return list;
        }
    }
    //use closure to pass filterFields and filterTerm to callback
    function filterCallback(filterFields, filterTerm) {
        return function(element) {
            return filterFields.some((filterField)=>{
                if(Array.isArray(element[filterField])){
                    return element[filterField].some(function(childElement){
                        return filterCallback(childElement);
                    })
                }else if(typeof element[filterField] === 'object'){
                    return filterCallback(element[filterField]);
                }
                return comparisonFunction(element[filterField], filterTerm);
            })
        }
    }
    //comparisonFunction - field value is populated, and either filterterm contains the fieldValue or visa-versa
    function comparisonFunction(fieldValue, filterTerm) {
        return fieldValue &&
        (String(fieldValue).toLowerCase().indexOf(filterTerm.toLowerCase()) >= 0
        || String(filterTerm).toLowerCase().indexOf(fieldValue.toLowerCase()) >= 0);
    }

//EXAMPLE USE:
    arr = [{name: "a", job: "b"}, {name:"c", job:"d"}];
    filterList(arr, "a", ["name"]); // => [{name: "a", job:"d"}]
    arr2 = [{name: "a", job: "b", employees: [{name: "d", job:"e" }]}, {name: "f", job: "g"}];
    filterList(arr2, "d", ["name", "employees"]); //=> [{name: "a", job:"b", employees: [{name: "d", job: "e"}]}]

```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**DRY your code** You reference `element[filterField]` quite a few times in `filterCallback`. It would be nicer to save the value in a standalone variable first - then you can reference that variable instead of doing object property lookup each time.

**Nested object bug** `filterCallback` returns a function, but here, if an array or object is found, you're returning a call of `filterCallback`, which will always be truthy, so the `.some` will pass, even when it shouldn't:

```
return filterFields.some((filterField) => {
  if (Array.isArray(element[filterField])) {
    return element[filterField].some(function(childElement) {
      return filterCallback(childElement); // <--- always truthy
    })
  } else if (typeof element[filterField] === 'object') {
    return filterCallback(element[filterField]); // <--- always truthy
  }
  return comparisonFunction(element[filterField], filterTerm); // <--- OK
})
```

```js
// No items should pass the test, but they do:



//if filterTerm or filterFields are empty, return original list
function filterList(list, filterTerm, filterFields) {
  if (filterTerm && filterFields.length > 0) {
    return list.filter(filterCallback(filterFields, filterTerm));
  } else {
    return list;
  }
}

//use closure to pass filterFields and filterTerm to callback
function filterCallback(filterFields, filterTerm) {
  return function(element) {
    return filterFields.some((filterField) => {
      if (Array.isArray(element[filterField])) {
        return element[filterField].some(function(childElement) {
          return filterCallback(childElement);
        })
      } else if (typeof element[filterField] === 'object') {
        return filterCallback(element[filterField]);
      }
      return comparisonFunction(element[filterField], filterTerm);
    })
  }
}
//comparisonFunction - field value is populated, and either filterterm contains the fieldValue or visa-versa
function comparisonFunction(fieldValue, filterTerm) {
  return fieldValue &&
    (String(fieldValue).toLowerCase().indexOf(filterTerm.toLowerCase()) >= 0 ||
      String(filterTerm).toLowerCase().indexOf(fieldValue.toLowerCase()) >= 0);
}

arr2 = [{
  name: "a",
  job: "b",
  employees: [{
    name: "z",
    job: "e"
  }]
}, {
  name: "f",
  job: "g"
}];
console.log(filterList(arr2, "d", ["name", "employees"])); //=> [{name: "a", job:"b", employees: [{name: "d", job: "e"}]}]
```

You need to call `filterCallback(filterFields, filterTerm)` first to get the filter function, then call the filter function with the value to check, eg:

```
return filterFields.some((filterField) => {
    const value = element[filterField];
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        return value.some(function (childElement) {
            return filterCallback(filterFields, filterTerm)(childElement);
        });
    } else if (typeof value === 'object') {
        return filterCallback(filterFields, filterTerm)(value);
    }
    return comparisonFunction(value, filterTerm); // <--- OK
});
```

```js
//if filterTerm or filterFields are empty, return original list
function filterList(list, filterTerm, filterFields) {
  if (filterTerm && filterFields.length > 0) {
    return list.filter(filterCallback(filterFields, filterTerm));
  } else {
    return list;
  }
}

//use closure to pass filterFields and filterTerm to callback
function filterCallback(filterFields, filterTerm) {
  return function(element) {
    return filterFields.some((filterField) => {
        const value = element[filterField];
        if (Array.isArray(value)) {
            return value.some(function (childElement) {
                return filterCallback(filterFields, filterTerm)(childElement);
            });
        } else if (typeof value === 'object') {
            return filterCallback(filterFields, filterTerm)(value);
        }
        return comparisonFunction(value, filterTerm); // <--- OK
    });
  }
}
//comparisonFunction - field value is populated, and either filterterm contains the fieldValue or visa-versa
function comparisonFunction(fieldValue, filterTerm) {
  return fieldValue &&
    (String(fieldValue).toLowerCase().indexOf(filterTerm.toLowerCase()) >= 0 ||
      String(filterTerm).toLowerCase().indexOf(fieldValue.toLowerCase()) >= 0);
}

//EXAMPLE USE:

arr = [{
  name: "a",
  job: "b"
}, {
  name: "c",
  job: "d"
}];
console.log(filterList(arr, "a", ["name"])); // => [{name: "a", job:"d"}]


arr2 = [{
  name: "a",
  job: "b",
  employees: [{
    name: "z",
    job: "e"
  }]
}, {
  name: "f",
  job: "g"
}];
console.log(filterList(arr2, "d", ["name", "employees"])); //=> [{name: "a", job:"b", employees: [{name: "d", job: "e"}]}]
```

**Precise variable names** To reduce bugs, best to name variables as precisely as possible - `filterCallback` isn't actually the callback used in `filter` or `some`, but it's a function which *creates* such a callback. Maybe call it `createFilterCallback` instead - that probably would've made the problem clearer at a glance.

**Implicit return** Since you're using ES6, you could consider using arrow functions too - their implicit return can make code much more concise. Less code means less surface area for bugs, and can sometimes make it easier to read.

**comparisonFunction** If you want to check whether a string includes another, in ES6, better to use `.includes(...)` than `.indexOf(...) >= 0`. You also have a potential bug - you do `String(fieldValue).toLowerCase()` and `String(filterTerm).toLowerCase()`, implying that you expect that the value or term may not be a string - but then you do `.indexOf(filterTerm.toLowerCase())` and `.indexOf(fieldValue.toLowerCase())`, which will throw if they aren't strings. Make sure to convert them to strings first:

```
const comparisonFunction = (fieldValue, filterTerm) => {
    const value = String(fieldValue).toLowerCase();
    const term = String(filterTerm).toLowerCase();
    return value && value.includes(term) || term.includes(value);
};
```

**`null` is an object too**, unfortunately, so:

```
}else if(typeof element[filterField] === 'object'){
    return filterCallback(element[filterField]);
}
```

will result in a recursive call, even when such a call won't make sense. The code *works*, but it's confusing flow. Better to only recurse if the value is an object *and* is not null.

**filterCallback** The whole `filterCallback` looks a bit ugly IMO. I'd simplify it a bit by not calling the whole function again recursively, but by declaring the function to filter elements by inside the function before returning it. Then, instead of recursing on `filterCallback`, recurse on that declared function:

```
const filterCallback = (filterFields, filterTerm) => {
  const testElement = element => filterFields.some((filterField) => {
    const value = element[filterField];
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
      return value.some(testElement);
    } else if (value && typeof value === 'object') {
      return testElement(value);
    } else {
      return value && comparisonFunction(value, filterTerm);
    }
  });
  return testElement;
}
```

In all:

```js
//if filterTerm or filterFields are empty, return original list
function filterList(list, filterTerm, filterFields) {
  if (filterTerm && filterFields.length > 0) {
    return list.filter(filterCallback(filterFields, filterTerm));
  } else {
    return list;
  }
}
//use closure to pass filterFields and filterTerm to callback
const filterCallback = (filterFields, filterTerm) => {
  const testElement = element => filterFields.some((filterField) => {
    const value = element[filterField];
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
      return value.some(testElement);
    } else if (value && typeof value === 'object') {
      return testElement(value);
    } else {
      return value && comparisonFunction(value, filterTerm);
    }
  });
  return testElement;
}
//comparisonFunction - field value is populated, and either filterterm contains the fieldValue or visa-versa
const comparisonFunction = (fieldValue, filterTerm) => {
  const value = String(fieldValue).toLowerCase();
  const term = String(filterTerm).toLowerCase();
  return value.includes(term) || term.includes(value);
};

//EXAMPLE USE:
arr = [{name: "a", job: "b"}, {name:"c", job:"d"}];
console.log(filterList(arr, "a", ["name"])); // => [{name: "a", job:"d"}]
arr2 = [{name: "a", job: "b", employees: [{name: "d", job:"e" }]}, {name: "f", job: "g"}];
console.log(filterList(arr2, "d", ["name", "employees"])); //=> [{name: "a", job:"b", employees: [{name: "d", job: "e"}]}]
```